# .NET IHttpHandler and HTTP/1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

How can I set the HTTP protocol version to HTTP/1.0 in the response of a IHttpHandler?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: +1 to why indeed.. HTTP/1.1 has many nice features like multiple domains on same IP that it should be considered the only standard to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can't control the protocol version that IIS responds with.

IIS should respond in a manner consistent with a 1.0 client if the request indicates 1.0 however the response header will still indicate that the server supports 1.1.

This is correct behaviour.